# Why does tracepath always display the first hop twice whereas traceroute does not?

Tags: linux, route, tracepath

Why does `tracepath` always display the first hop twice :

```
$ tracepath -n X.Y.Z.T
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  172.16.5.2                                            0.586ms
 1:  172.16.5.2                                            0.420ms
 2:  no reply
 3:  X.Y.Z.T                                           6.199ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 3 back 3
```

whereas `traceroute` does not :

```
$ traceroute -n X.Y.Z.T
traceroute to X.Y.Z.T (X.Y.Z.T), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.16.5.2  0.672 ms  0.705 ms  0.723 ms
 2  * * *
 3  X.Y.Z.T  1.192 ms  1.220 ms  1.218 ms
```

By the way, `172.16.5.2` is one of the two physical routers in the gateway group, the logical gateway router is `172.16.5.1` :

```
$ ip route get X.Y.Z.T
X.Y.Z.T via 172.16.5.1 dev ens160 src 172.16.5.X uid 1000
    cache
```

EDIT0 : Using MTU=1500 :

```
$ tracepath -n X.Y.Z.T -l 1500
 1:  172.16.5.2                                            0.598ms
 2:  no reply
 3:  X.Y.Z.T                                           6.368ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 3 back 3
```

Using MTU=1501 :

```
$ tracepath -n X.Y.Z.T -l 1501
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  172.16.5.2                                            0.600ms
 1:  172.16.5.2                                            0.394ms
 2:  no reply
 3:  X.Y.Z.T                                           6.139ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 3 back 3
```

Using MTU=3*1500+1 :

```
$ tracepath -n X.Y.Z.T -l $((3*1500+1))
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  172.16.5.2                                            0.653ms
 1:  172.16.5.2                                            1.239ms
 2:  no reply
 3:  X.Y.Z.T                                           6.098ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 3 back 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the initial packet length is too large. Try with option `-l` to set the packet size to max. your mtu. If mtu is 1500, `-l 1500` will be ok, while `-l 1501` will bring the double figure.

Edit: tracepath is inconsistent with detecting pmtu. Sometimes here it's 1460, sometimes 1500. The lower value works in every case, in fact as small as 100 should do.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my new EDIT0 ? Why using an MTU=3*1500+1 does not get my 3 lines of the same hop in the `tracepath` result ?

Comment: Eh, it does get the duplicates?!

Answer (score 0):

according to `man tracepath`, OUTPUT section

> The first column shows TTL of the probe, followed by colon. Usually value of TTL is obtained from reply from network, but sometimes reply does not contain necessary information and we have to
> guess it. In this case the number is followed by ?.

Comment: You are talking about `1?: [LOCALHOST]` line right ?. `LOCALHOST` is not the first hop. My question is talking about the first hop. I am wondering why does the first hop line is displayed twice ?